# Plotting values range against a moving mean for each interval RStudio

Tags: r, statistics

I'm trying to plot the mean fat percentage for each age group in RStudio. Specifically, I want to barplot the age range (18-24 & 24-30 & 30+) against the mean fat percentage (y-axis) for each of the age groups mentioned. Not sure how to approach it since I'm new to RStudio. I've linked the data for reference: https://www2.stetson.edu/~jrasp/data/BodyFat.xls

Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could create a grouping column with `cut`, then do the `summarise` and use `ggplot` to plot

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(ggplot2)
 df1 %>% 
   group_by(AGE_RANGE = cut(AGE, breaks = c(-Inf, 18, 24, 30, Inf),
        labels = c('<18', '18-24', '24-30', '30+'))) %>% 
   summarise(MeanFat = mean(BODYFAT)) %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x = AGE_RANGE, y = MeanFat)) +
           geom_col()#+
           #xlab("Age Group") +  
           #ylab("Mean Fat Percentage" )
```

[image]

#### data

```
library(readxl)
df1 <- read_excel(file.choose())
```

Comment: could you please explain the last line in the code
"ggplot(aes(x = AGE_RANGE, y = MeanFat)) +
           geom_col()"

Comment: @ZaidAlKaraghool. the `ggplot` line?

Comment: Yes. Why add the "geom_col()"?

Comment: @ZaidAlKaraghool sorry, that is similar to `geom_bar`, but more concise i.e. it is plotting the mean of the Fat as bar for each AGE_RANGE

Comment: Thank you! I noticed the axes are labeled according to the variables. Is there a way to change that? For example, x-axis = "Age Group" and y-axis ="Mean Fat Percentage"

Comment: @ZaidAlKaraghool you can add `+xlab("Age Group") +
  ylab("Mean Fat Percentage" )` at the ebd

Comment: Accepted. Thank you.